# move to another php page using javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to move from page to another after clicking on li goes to javascript function that have the request to go to another page .

Here is my js code :

```
function profile(usertype){
 alert(usertype);
 window.location="comehere.php";
}
```

index.php page code :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <script src="style.js"></script>
 </head>
<body>
 <div id="Menu-bar" >
   <ul>
  <li style="position:absolute;left:430px;Top:0;"><a 
   href="javascript:profile('Admin');" class="active" id="report-print">
     <img src="images/users.png"></a></li>
   </div>
 </ul>
 </body>
```

comehre.php page :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
<h1>HALLOOOOOOOOOOOO  </h1>
</head>
```

By clicking on `li`,I only get the alert and doesn't move to another page , why?

Comment: should be `window.location.href`

Comment: i've tried it and didn't work :\ !

Comment: is it that it does not move to the specified page? or it relocates, just not to the right page?

Comment: `alert()` halts the JavaScript process in some cases. You should look for a different solution. Can you use `console.log()` instead?

Comment: @Akintunde007 setting `window.location` is valid, it is just a shorter way to setting the underlying href property

Comment: @Akintunde007 it shows the alert only doesn't move at all

Comment: @JayBlanchard i used the alert to see if he can read the function so i'll delete it , you mean console.log(comehere.php)?

Comment: `console.log(usertype)`. In any case, remove the `alert()` and the redirect will work.

Comment: Are you closing the `alert` dialog? Navigation will not happen until after the `alert` is closed.

Answer (score 0):

I've tested here and works fine. Looks like you put in javascript "comehere", when must be "comehre" - without the 'e'